# Comparing values in a 2-Dimensional Array with each other

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, comparison, duplicates

I had a Computer Science exam today. In this I have to write a number of different algorithms. Most of them I managed to do, but one of the first questions totally threw me off.

A 2 dimensional array was used to store digits in a 3 * 3 Grid of a sudoku game. The grid contained numbers from 1 to 9. For those of you unfamiliar with sudoku, you are only allowed to use each number once in a 3*3 grid. 
The question asked me to write a checkGrid() algorithm to compare the values in the array with each other to check if there are any duplicates. If none are found, "Success" should be output, if there are double values, "Failure" should be output. 
How can I achieve this? I really don't have a clue.

I spent way to much time in the exam trying to figure this out and barely managed to finish my paper -.- Maybe you should listen to teachers when they tell you to skip a question that you don't know to come back to it later...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku_solving_algorithms

Answer (score 0):

There are many options, but the easiest way I can think of is using a `Set`:

```
public void checkGrid(int[][] grid) {
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (set.contains(grid[i][j])) {
                System.out.println("Failure");
                return;
            } else {
                set.add(grid[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Success");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I would have never thought of this. Now I know for the future...